# Can you make a struct containing an array member, where each array element also has a name?

Tags: c++, reference, variable-assignment

Is it possible in C++ to refer to the same variable using different names without using the preprocessor?

To achieve the same effect as this pseudocode

```
struct vec3f {
    float values[3];
};

struct color : public vec3f {
    #define r values[0]
    #define g values[1]
    #define b values[2]
};

color c;
c.r = 0.5f;
```

The following has the right semantics except it allocates space in the struct for the 3 references:

```
struct color : public vec3f {
    float& r;
    float& g;
    float& b;
    color() : r(values[0]), g(values[1]), b(values[2]) { }
};
```

Is there a way to get this compile-time name substitution without increasing the size of the struct?

Answer (score 10):

How about this?

```
struct vec3f {
    float[3] values;
};

struct color : public vec3f
{
    float& r() { return values[0]; }
    float& g() { return values[1]; }
    float& b() { return values[2]; }
    const float& r() const { return values[0]; }
    const float& g() const { return values[1]; }
    const float& b() const { return values[2]; }
};
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the brackets but this is definitely the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that you want to use inheritance in this case. You might be better of with a plain old `union` type:

```
typedef float vec3f[3];
union color {
   vec3f values;
   struct {
      float r;
      float g;
      float b;
   };
};

color c;
c.values[0] = 10;
assert( c.r == 10 );
```

Comment: I think that'd have to be `c.values.values[0]` sadly :(

Comment: @MooingDuck: ?? The type `vec3f` is a *typedef*, not the original `struct` and the code is correct as it is. `c.values.values[0]` would be a compiler error.

Comment: whoa, failed to notice the typedef.

Comment: Unfortunately this is undefined behavior, because arrays do not participate in the "common initial subsequence" rule permitted unions to be read through a different member than was written.

Answer (score 1):

**ALTERNATIVE 1**

You always create a temporary when you want a variable alias. With a good optimizer you will hardly see any performance difference.

```
struct vec3f
{
    float values[3];
};

struct tempvec
{
    float &r;
    float &g;
    float &b;

    tempvec( vec3f& bar )
        :r(bar.values[0]) 
        , g(bar.values[1]) 
        , b(bar.values[2]){}
};

int main() 
{
    vec3f temp;
    temp.values[0] = 2.40f;

    //when you want to alias values[0] as r do this
    tempvec(temp).r = 42;
    tempvec(temp).g = 42;

    return 0;    
}
```

**ALTERNATIVE 2**

If you can verify that memory layout of `vec3f` and `vec3c` is the same on your platform and OS.. taking into account **[padding/alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)** etc... you can do

```
struct vec3f
{
    float values[3];
};

struct vec3c
{
    float r,g,b;
};

int main() 
{
    vec3f temp;
    temp.values[0] = 2.40f;

    vec3c* alias  = reinterpret_cast<vec3c*>(&temp);

    alias->r = 4.2f;
    alias->g = 4.2f;
    alias->b = 4.2f;

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Your alternative 2 made me discover the cast operator, so `color` could be written as `struct color { float r, g, b; operator vec3f&() { return *((vec3f*)this); };`.

Answer (score 1):

As it happens, I first saw a really neat [trick for this](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/261920-a-slick-trick-in-c/) several years ago.

The idea is that you give the class named variables in order, and then also have a `static const` member of array-of-pointer-to-member type. The `operator[]` is overloaded to look up the appropriate pointer-to-member, use it to select the member from `this`, and return a reference.

This works because pointer-to-members are not ordinary pointers; they're a little more magical than that. (This is what enables you to create un-bound pointers to member functions, and why they can't be used where plain function pointers are expected).

It also means that you don't have to use any casting tricks, rely on any kinds of alignment, non-portable anonymous-union behaviour, or memory layout guarantees, and you still get to refer to the components of the structure as named fields instead of via accessor functions.

Comment: While a neat trick, I don't see how this helps when `color` should be a `vec3f`.

Comment: @MooingDuck If we're going to do something as strange as treating colours as vectors, I hardly see how it matters what direction the inheritance goes in, or even that there is inheritance... so you'd make a `color` with the overloaded `operator[]` and `r/g/b` members, and then typedef `vec3f` to it.